# Usage of first child on 0th member of array

Tags: javascript, arrays

In the code below, of the Lynda Essential Js Training I can't understand why firstChild is being called when we are already calling 0th member of the arrray.

> xhr.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("heading")[0].firstChild.nodeValue;

The complete code below :

```
 (function() {

        var link = document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        link.onclick = function() {
    // Request
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    // Handle on readystate
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if((xhr.readyState ==4) && (xhr.status == 200 || xhr.status == 304)) {
            var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
            var heading = xhr.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("heading")[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
            var h2 = document.createElement("h2");
            var h2Text = document.createTextNode(heading);
            h2.appendChild(h2Text);
            body.appendChild(h2);

            body.removeChild(link); 
        }
    };
    // Open the request
    xhr.open("GET","files/ajax.xml",true);
    //send
    xhr.send(null)

        return false;
    };

    }) ();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means it's calling the first child **OF** the first `heading` element (though I assume you only have one).

`xhr.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("heading")` returns an array (or a nodeList, to be more accurate) of all the heading elements in the response

`xhr.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("heading")[0]` returns the first element from the array above

and finally:

`xhr.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("heading")[0].firstChild` returns the first child of the first heading element from above

---

Imagine a structure like this:

```
<heading>      <---- this is the getElementsByTagName("heading")[0]
   <child/>    <---- and this is its first child
   <child/>
</heading>
<heading>
   <child/>
   <child/>
</heading>
<heading>
   <child/>
   <child/>
</heading>
```

Answer (score 0):

[getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document/getElementsByTagName) itself returns an `HTMLCollection`. Therefore,

```
xhr.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("heading")[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
```

is saying get the first `heading` element. Then, get the first child of that *first* heading element.